# How much power is needed to keep ideal gas in a fix volume?

Tags: thermodynamics, entropy, ideal-gas

I was playing with the idea of entropy and an interesting thought came out. Imagine a physical cube with side $a$. Inside the cube is $N$ particles of an ideal gas at a temperature $T$. One particle of the gas has the mass of $m$.

[image]

It can be seen that each particle would be moving at a velocity of v, bouncing off the wall of the cube. Let's take a particle that starts moving at the center of a face of the cube and bouncing off the centers of other faces of the cube. Now if we replace the cube with a series of machine guns surrounding the what is now an imaginary cube, the guns are programmed so that whenever it sees a particle about to pass the "cube", it will fire an identical particle at speed v so that it will hit the particle in the "cube" at the exact moment and angle so that the inside particle is steered back inside the "cube" just like when there was a physical cube.

[image]

If this happens, the frequency of the gun getting shot will be the frequency of a particle going to the side of the imaginary cube. This is:

$$f = \frac{v\sqrt{2}}{a}$$ 
where $v$ is the velocity of a particle and $a$ is the side length of the cube

For each time a gun fires, in order to work, it must give its "bullet" a total of kinetic energy is:
$$KE = \frac{1}{2} mv^2$$
So the power of the guns system would be:
$$P = KE.f = \frac{v\sqrt{2}}{a} \frac{1}{2} mv^2 = \frac{mv^3}{a\sqrt{2}}$$

Since $$v = \sqrt{\frac{3kT}{m}}$$
so:
$$P = \frac{m}{a\sqrt{2}} \biggl(\frac{3kT}{m}\biggl)^\frac{3}{2}$$
$$P = \frac{(3kT)^\frac{3}{2}}{a\sqrt{2m}}$$
If we imagine that all particles move like this (I think this will happen if we take the average of where each particles hit the "cube") and write the equation in term of $V$:
$$P = \frac{N(3kT)^\frac{3}{2}}{V^\frac{1}{3}\sqrt{2m}}$$
So I concluded that this is the minimum power required to keep a collection of $N$ particles of ideal gas at temperature $T$ in a volume $V$ (without sqreading all over the place).

However, this seems really wrong, because the power required is incredibly large. There is not a lot of energy required if we can reuse the kinetic energy of bounced of "bullets", but the amount of power of the gun system is still very large.

For example, in order to keep 1 mol of Hydrogen gas in a 1m^3 space at a temperature of 273K, the amount of power needed is $1.2516 * 10^7 W$

Can someone tell me whether this is correct or not and can we really conclude that everything is constantly emitting energy and get them back constantly?

Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: Not sure if/how this will affect your answer, but an ideal gas isn't a bunch of particles all moving at the same speed; rather, the speeds of the particles follow the Boltzmann distribution.

Comment: oh yeah, the same speed thing was just an initial assumption to make things simpler, it does not affect the answer since the velocity I used was basically the average velocity.

Comment: Are you sure it doesn't affect the answer? Have you checked? Because in the Boltzmann distribution, the majority of particles are actually moving at _below_ the average speed (due to the high-energy, low-probability tail of the distribution skewing the average upward).

Comment: since I imagined that there is a particle moving at the average velocity, having an amount of average kinetic energy, then multiply it to the number of particles to get the total amount of kinetic energy, it should not matter. Please correct me if I'm wrong since I'm still quite new the concept of Boltzmann distribution.

Comment: It won't affect the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to keep firing new particles at it. Two identical particles could both be trapped in identical boxes, colliding with each other and confining each other, thus requiring no energy input. When you keep firing more particles at it, the same particles are reflected back with the same speed so the energy entering the system equals the energy leaving it. This means no energy input is required to confine a gas. This makes sense because you wouldn't expect a container to lose energy ad infinitum.

Comment: Aren't after the two particles collided with each other, they will bounce off each other and travel outside the "box" region, since there is no real physical box? The total amount of energy is conserved ( meaning the amount of energy that goes into the system equal the amount that leaves), but I think that there must always be a release and re-absorption of energy by the guns or the "box".

Comment: I think I misunderstand. Isn't there a physical box that is missing a side?

Comment: oh no, the box is replaced entirely by practically a large number of tiny guns surrounding the space

Comment: Ah ok sorry, but my point still kind of remains. No energy is transferred to the gas particles, only momentum.

Comment: yes, no new energy is transferred to the gas particles, what I thought of is that in order to keep the gas particles in a confined volume, there must be a constant process of releasing and re-absorbing energy either by the guns by catching the bounced off bullets or by the wall in some way

Comment: And I think that if we only take into account the energy involved during the firing process (released energy), we can calculate the frequency or the power of that energy being released.

Comment: I see what you mean now. I think that for your process of firing other identical particles at the gas your calculation is correct but if you confine the particles using a container no energy transfer and reabsorption is needed.

Comment: no that's what I meant, I think that it's impossible to make a box so that no such process of constant release and re-absorption take place, they may take place at a quantum level, that I'm not so sure. Since the re-absorption process is never perfect, this also means that there can never be a perfect insulator

Comment: A real box is made of a large number of atoms bound together such that they aren't able to move freely. They vibrate with the same average kinetic energy as the gas as they are in equilibrium. When a gas collides with a box particle, sometimes energy is lost and sometimes it is gained, depending on which one has more energy. Because the particles are biund together, they can be modelled as a plane with much greater mass than the gas particles. Your model isn't applicable as no new particles are added to the system and the momentum transfer is instantaneous, requiring no transfer of energy.

Comment: I think the model can be applied if the guns can somehow recapture the one-shot particles and get all of their kinetic energy back. Since this is an arbitrary process, its time can be thought to be very small, or instantaneous. I just think that since the two processes have the same result, this may also be how a box work and it's impossible to stop the release and reabsorption of energy from happening.

Comment: What my idea is saying is that in order to confine an amount of gas in a constant volume at a constant temperature, there must be energy being released and in an ideal environment, getting absorbed again by the environment and the rate of this energy getting released can be calculated as the power.

Comment: But if the process is instantaneous then the power you calculated has no physical meaning because transferring and reabsorbing energy in zero time is the same as transferring zero energy. The energy transfer in your model is a measure of how much energy is missing before it is reabsorbed. In the instantaneous case this has no real meaning.

Comment: I'm so sorry about the instantaneous thing, I made a mistake there. I think that in a real-life scenario where you want to build a machine that can confine a certain amount of gas inside a volume at a constant temperature, then you need to have an output of power P and then you can re-absorb the energy that's getting out of the system. A box does this in a really short time but if your time interval is larger, you can still work if the machine has P power output.

Comment: what I meant when I said instantaneous was that the "gun system" can be thought to replicate every kind of tool or machine that traps the air there, including a wall.

Comment: This makes sense but I don't see why a real life wall would have to behave like your gun model

Comment: I think as a particle hits a side of the wall, there must be a force coming from the wall to change its velocity direction, this may take place at a macrocosmic scale. I think that the force generated comes from some kind of energy output at a constant power rate. The  time interval between this process and the retrieval of energy is 0 in an ideal wall, but in the real world, the time interval is not 0, it can be really small though